# Spark configuration "spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate" does not working strictly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I've got 2 receivers in my spark-streaming application. When I set `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` to 1000, the max rate should be 2 * 1000 theoretically. But in fact, the rate was often a little more than 2000/s, sometimes would be 3000/s, is that normal or there's something wrong?

P.S. Spark Version is 1.4.0, the data is from Kafka. And the configuration is as below:

```scala
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g") 
conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC")  // executor 
conf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC")  // driver 
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", "1000")  // maxRate: 1K per second per receiver
conf.set("spark.streaming.blockInterval", "100")
conf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "3")
conf.set("spark.shuffle.consolidateFile", "true") 
conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") // not documented but works in 1.4.0
conf.set("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs://" + nameService + "/spark/app_history")
```

Comment: @zero323 Thank you for the advise, I've already update the answer. And yes, the maxRate configuration works, because when I change maxRate into a high value, the actual rate gets higher too. e.g. If I set maxRate to 20,000, then the rate would be around 40,000, but sometime higher.